# Помогите пожалуйста. как сделать так чтобы пользователь смог выбрать тип операции с помощью цифр от 1 до 4

Tags: c#

```
switch (op)
        {
            case Operator.add:
                result = Operand1 + Operand2;
                break;
            case Operator.substract:
                result = Operand1 - Operand2;
                break;
            case Operator.multiplay:
                result = Operand1 * Operand2;
                break;
            case Operator.divide:
                result = Operand1 / Operand2;
                break;
```

Comment: Выбрать где?....

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такую конструкцию:

```
  switch (Console.ReadKey().Key)
  {
      case ConsoleKey.D1:

           break;
      case ConsoleKey.D2:

           break;
  }
```